# Add view at point on screen in LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to dynamically add views to a view on different points on screen using LinearLayout.
This the view I'm trying to add the views to:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playerContainerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#B86262"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_drawer" />
```

Code for adding the views (TextView):

```
fun addLabelToViewAtLocation(view:LinearLayout, x:Int, y:Int) {
    var tv2 = TextView(this)
    tv2.text = x.toString() + "," + y.toString()
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    var ll2 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            200,
            60)
    tv2.x = x.toFloat()
    tv2.y = y.toFloat()

    tv2.setLayoutParams(ll2)
    view.addView(tv2,index)
    view.requestLayout()
}
```

And function calls:

```
val pcv = this.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.playerContainerView)
    pcv.post{
        addLabelToViewAtLocation(pcv,10, 10)
        addLabelToViewAtLocation(pcv,0, 0)
        addLabelToViewAtLocation(pcv,200, 60)}
```

So the text views are being added but they do not appear in the correct location -
The `0,0` text view that should be on the top left corner appears at the top right corner of the `10,10` text view because it was added first.

From what it seems, this strangely acts as a relative layout instead of a linear layout but i just can't find how to fix this.

Thoughts?

Comment: That's correct right? `LinearLayout` is drawing the first `TextView`, then when next `TextView` is added, it calculates the position in the remaining space, unless weight is set.

Comment: This is the situation, yes. I don't want to add the view relatively to the previous one, i want it to be relative to the parent and thats it. how can weight fix this? @VarshaKulkarni

Comment: Perhaps using ConstraintLayout?

Comment: I might give it a go, will try relative layout instead and anchor it to the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` with alignWithParent = true, updated add view function:

```
fun addLabelToViewAtLocation(view: RelativeLayout, x:Int, y:Int, text:String) {
    var tv = TextView(this)
    tv.text = text
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    var rl = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    rl.alignWithParent = true
    tv.x = x.toFloat()
    tv.y = y.toFloat()

    tv.setLayoutParams(rl)
    view.addView(tv)
    view.requestLayout()
}
```

Just could not make the LinearLayout work no matter what i tried